# Diego Migration: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, migration, ibm-cloud, diego

I have existing node.js application running on the IBM Bluemix DEA runtime. 
I have tried to migrate it to the Diego, migration process completed without any errors.
But when I am trying application route I am getting '502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.' error. 
Migration is done using the "Migrate to Diego" button.

From application console:

```
7/12/2017 8:59:28 AM    OUT STG Staging complete
7/12/2017 8:59:28 AM    OUT STG Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
7/12/2017 8:59:28 AM    OUT STG Uploading build artifacts cache...
7/12/2017 8:59:28 AM    OUT STG Uploading droplet...
7/12/2017 8:59:29 AM    OUT STG Uploaded build artifacts cache (18.2M)
7/12/2017 8:59:34 AM    OUT STG Uploaded droplet (38M)
7/12/2017 8:59:34 AM    OUT STG Uploading complete
7/12/2017 8:59:34 AM    OUT STG Destroying container
7/12/2017 8:59:34 AM    OUT CELL    Creating container
7/12/2017 8:59:35 AM    OUT CELL    Successfully created container
7/12/2017 8:59:37 AM    OUT STG Successfully destroyed container
7/12/2017 8:59:40 AM    OUT APP > MyReactApp@1.0.0 start /home/vcap/app
7/12/2017 8:59:40 AM    OUT APP > node index.js
7/12/2017 8:59:40 AM    OUT APP Example app listening at http://:::3001
......
......
7/12/2017 9:00:08 AM    OUT RTR myreactapp.w3ibm.mybluemix.net - [12/07/2017:09:00:08.768 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 0 67 "https://console.w3ibm.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" 169.53.228.149:13440 x_forwarded_for:"9.84.35.70" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:30f4de63-8ac9-4502-6d43-eb1eec7e1e02 response_time:0.003236115 app_id:4c4861e7-7ad1-4d1d-a838-b64d0e47408d x_global_transaction_id:"2500071025"
```

Answer (score 1):

`OUT APP Example app listening at http://:::3001`

Check that your app is listening on the correct host and port. It should be `0.0.0.0` and the port assigned by Cloud Foundry through the `PORT` environment variable (probably 8080).

The deprecated `VCAP_APP_HOST` and `VCAP_APP_PORT` environment variables are not set by Diego.

Comment: As I understand the CloudFoundry supplies host and port when staging application. In the DEA I see than port assigned dinamically with different values.  
In our application we don't assign or use such env. variables.

Comment: Have dad a second thought, you are absolutely right. Thanks, now all works fine.

Comment: The way to say thank you on SO is to accept the answer ;-).